# How to return the value of the method in java inside another method

Tags: java

​what I want to ask may seem stupid but since I am beginner I dare to ask.
Actually I have a method that returns a string  `DataReader.getInstance().getData();`
 and I want to replace the content of below string which is `"data is assigned"` by the value that this method returns.

```
response.put("data is assigned", + result.get());
```

Is there any nice way of doing that instead of just simply replacing. The problem is that when I replace like this:

```
String value = DataReader.getInstance().getData();
response.put(value + result.get());
```

it complains that it needs a try, catch and when I do that

```
try {
    String value =  DataReader.getInstance().getData();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then Value is just defined inside the trycatch! but anyway I need a clever way other than that.
Any idea.

Thanks,

Comment: You *should* have the try-catch. Just put the `response.put()` *within* the try-block.

Comment: If you get an `IOException`, then data **isn't** assigned and if you just swallow the exception and basically lie to the clients of your code, you'll run into similar problems later on. Deal with the exception appropriately, they're part of the phase space of your application.

Answer (score 4):

Define `value` outside the try :

```
String value = null;
try {
    value =  DataReader.getInstance().getData();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @user3409650 If `getInstance()` or `getData()` may throw `IOException`, you must either catch that exception, or declare that the method that contains this call `throws IOException`.

Comment: @OP There are. But it is important for you to understand this methodology before moving on to other solutions.

Comment: @user3409650 Don't try to find another way. Exceptions serve a well-defined purpose and are an important part of working code, not just something that was tagged on to certain methods just to annoy you. The world is full of buggy, hard-to-maintain, and sometimes outright dangerous code that was written by coders who thought exceptions are just a nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of catching an exception is to do something with it: log it, use it to decide what to do next, whatever. Usually for IOExceptions you're just done, all you can do is log it.

The reason for throwing exceptions is because usually the place where an exception is thrown is not the place where it can be handled meaningfully, throwing the exception lets the program leave its current context, which the exception has demonstrated to be invalid, and go to a different place, where the program can catch the exception and respond appropriately.

Here the exception is telling you what you are trying to do can't be done, so there's really no point in continuing. The exception gives you away to abort and regroup.

You could change your example to:

```
try {
    return DataReader.getInstance().getData();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

But then the callers have to add code to check for the case where you return null. You're better off letting the exception be thrown (aborting the current operation), then letting exceptions be handled in a central spot that logs them. Then your method is just

```
String myMethod() throws IOException {
    return DataReader.getInstance().getData();
}
```

Comment: Mmmm... is this method `myMethod` implementation really more convenient?

Comment: @Andremoniy: i don't understand your question. i'm just trying to tell the OP to think about exception-handling rather than eat it reflexively.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions:

**1st:**

```
try {
    response.put(DataReader.getInstance().getData() + result.get());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**2nd**

```
try {
    String value = DataReader.getInstance().getData();
    response.put(value + result.get());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**3rd:**

```
String value = null;
try {
    value = DataReader.getInstance().getData();
    response.put(value + result.get());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**4th:**

```
String value = null;
try {
    value = DataReader.getInstance().getData();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
response.put(value + result.get());
```

**5th**

Write a method to get data:

```
private String getReaderData()
{
    try {
        return DataReader.getInstance().getData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle exception - throw the same, throw wrapper, return null
        throw new IllegalStateException("No Data Found in the reader");
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
response.put(getReaderData() + result.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to present asnwers one more way.

Sometimes (e.g. in more complex situations) it is convenient to define new method, that wraps this try...catch code:

```
response.put(buildVale() + result.get());
...
private static String buildValue() {
    try {
         return DataReader.getInstance().getData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }        
}
```

Comment: This is a rather poor practice, I wouldn't recommend it to anyone. Instead of dealing with the exception, you just wrap it into something that it shouldn't be wrapped into.

Comment: @biziclop Absolutelly incorrect interpretation of my suggestion. I just suggest method wrapping. You are talking about exception handling. Where is the logic?

Comment: @biziclop P.S. wrapping non-runtime exceptions into runtime - isn't actually bad practice. If itsn't just your opinion-based conclusion - prove it by an authoritative source.

Comment: You wrap your exception into a `RuntimeException`, that's the wrong bit. Wrap it into an exception that makes sense on that level, otherwise what you get is just a workaround.

Comment: If you can't see why using a naked `RuntimeException` is wrong by yourself, read the "Throw exceptions appropriate to the abstraction" section of Effective Java.

Comment: No-one said wrapping non-runtime exceptions into the appropriate subclass of `RuntimeException` is wrong. But the emphasis is on "the appropriate subclass". And only do it if the condition isn't recoverable on that level. A lot of conditions are recoverable.